# Create table using two with clauses

Tags: sql, oracle, with-clause

I want to create table and use two with, here is my code:

```
Create Table profitTry
As
With ctsWithSplit as (select c.Tdate, c.Symbol, c.close * coalesce(s.post/s.pre, 1) as new_close
 from ctsTry c left join splits s 
on c.Tdate = s.Tdate and c.symbol = s.symbol),

delta as
( select a.Tdate as TDate,  a.Symbol as Symbol, a.price-b.price as Pdelta, b.price as oldPrice
   from ctsWithSplit a, ctsWithSplit b
   where a.TDate-b.TDate=1 and a.Symbol=b.Symbol)

select  a.TDate,a.Symbol, (a.delta-coalesce(b.dividend,0))/delta.oldPrice as percentage
From delta a left join dividend b
On a.Tdate=b.Tdate and a.Symbol=b.Symbol
```

There is an error saying "table not existed", is it because my 2nd with clause please?

Comment: Maybe `ctsTry` or `dividend` don't exist.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I checked. There are. Are there grammar error with the WITH clause please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One definite problem is in your outer `select`:

```
select  a.TDate,a.Symbol, (a.delta-coalesce(b.dividend,0))/delta.oldPrice as percentage
-----------------------------------------------------------^
From delta a left join dividend b
On a.Tdate=b.Tdate and a.Symbol=b.Symbol
```

There is no `delta`.  You mean `a`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I found the error on line 4. it should be table name "split " while  I have "splits". But split is the keyword in oracle. How can I fix it please?

Comment: Thanks I fix it. I just want to make sure the create table and with clause is working